# Onedrive for business Rest API - Multi user multi tenant

Tags: onedrive

I am quiet new at Office365 and Rest API's.

I found my self searching every post,article or blog looking for the correct way of working with Onedrive for business Rest API.

The URL that OneDrive for Business published is :

**OneDrive for Business:** https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me

I am a user in one of the tenant with no admin permissions,I event got my user ID.

But what is the correct syntax for that ?

Thank you
Asaf

Answer (score 0):

looking into your question, are you asking syntax for the URL? 
If it is then your business domain name with which you have registered like if your business domain name is 'myonedrive' and then your mail id should be 'user@myonedrive.onmicrosoft.com' and the URL would be 'http://myonedrive-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me/'.

Follow this official doc for further instructions on how to authenticate and use OneDrive for business rest API - 'https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm'
which provides all the details and endpoints of rest API.

As in your case for different tenant i.e., for different organisation you will have different tenant and the URL changes accordingly and users are mapped accordingly with the organisation.